# Sharing multiple variables between methods in Java

Tags: java

What is the best way to pass multiple variables between methods? I have done it one way in which there is a return statement in the first method, but I want to access every variable from the first method in the second method. The variable "value0" in method "addTasks0" is not recognized.

```
public Integer addValues(){
int value0 = sliderExample.getValue();
int value1 = sliderExample1.getValue();
int value2 = sliderExample2.getValue();
int value3 = sliderExample3.getValue();
int value4 = sliderExample4.getValue();
int value5 = sliderExample5.getValue();
int value6 = sliderExample6.getValue();
int value7 = sliderExample7.getValue();
int totalValue = (value0 + value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 + value5 + value6 +     value7);

return totalValue;
}


public void addTasks0(){      
    Integer totalValue = addValues();

      if (totalValue <= 100) {
      progressBar.setValue(value0);
  }
  else{
      int overkill = (totalValue - 100);
      int margin = (value0 - overkill);
      String taskTitle = inputText.getText();
      String marginmessage = "The maximum priority of " + taskTitle + " is" + Integer.toString(margin) + "%";
      sliderExample.setValue(0);
          //custom title, warning icon
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, marginmessage, "Check Math", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
  }
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, couldn't you return an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass in a list of key value pairs where each function can access the requisite data by using a specific key name

```
Map<String key,Object value) params;
...
funcA(Map params){
 params.add(somePredefinedKey,newProperty);
...
funcB(params);
}

funcB(Map params){
Object paramA=params.get(somePredefinedKey);
```

...
    }

This is particularaly useful if you are passing your parameters through multiple methods in sequence

Comment: I used this method in an application with Threads that need set property for each Thread, because when a Thread set property, others Threads see change because all properties are common for  all Threads (as far as I know). I used key with Thread.currentThread().getId(); (instead String I used Long) so each Thread can read his own Object.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are showing that you have still access to the `sliderExample` in the `addTasks0` method, so as in `addValues` you can again do

```
int value0 = sliderExample.getValue();
```

in the `addTasks0` method.  You do not need to pass the value.

However if you really want to you could return an int array from `addValues` where arr[0] == `value0` and arr[1] == `totalValue`

or of course you could just move these variables as class fields

Comment: I originally had that, but I have 8 different tasks so I wanted to clean up the code a little bit and put the summation of the slider values in a separate method and just pass the value that I need. For example addTask1 would get value1, addTask2 would get value2, etc. I will try the array method.

Comment: Of course you could just move these variables as class fields

Comment: Can you give me an example of moving them as class fields? Do you mean  taking them out of the method and having them be a global variable within the class?

Comment: Make a new class that has fields for all the stuff you want to return, and return an instance of the new class.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your variables in the beginning of your class so that they are accessible to all methods of the class.

```
class ClassName {
    private int value0, value1, value2...;

    public Integer addValues() {
        value0 = sliderExample.getValue();
        value1 = sliderExample1.getValue();
        value2 = sliderExample2.getValue();
        // etc.
    }

    public void addTasks0() {
        Integer totalValue = addValues();

        if (totalValue <= 100) {
            progressBar.setValue(value0)    // Initialized in addValues method
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
ArrayList<SliderExample> sliderExamples = new ArrayList<>();

public int addValues() {
    int sum = 0;
    for(SliderExample se: sliderExamples) sum += se.getValue();
    return sum;
}

public void addTask(int taskNr) {
    SliderExample se = sliderExamples.get(taskNr);
    int value = se.getValue();
    ...
}
```